# 'The type or namespace name missing'

Tags: android, xamarin

I followed every step properly to develop an app in xamarin studio as shown in(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/)
But, After building the solution there 11 errors as
1.'The type or namespace name **Android** could not be found.(Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)' 
2.'The type or namespace name **Activity** could not be found.(Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
3.'The type or namespace name **Bundle** could not be found.(Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'
How to get rid of these errors? Please help

Here's the code---

```
    using System;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Android.OS;

        namespace PhoneWord
        {
         [Activity (Label = "PhoneWord", MainLauncher = true, Icon ="@drawable/icon")]
  public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


        // Get our UI controls from the loaded layout:
        EditText phoneNumberText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PhoneNumberText);
        Button translateButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.TranslateButton);
        Button callButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CallButton);
        // Disable the "Call" button
        callButton.Enabled = false;

        // Add code to translate number
        string translatedNumber = string.Empty;

        translateButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            // Translate user's alphanumeric phone number to numeric
            translatedNumber = Core.PhonewordTranslator.ToNumber(phoneNumberText.Text);
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(translatedNumber))
            {
                callButton.Text = "Call";
                callButton.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                callButton.Text = "Call " + translatedNumber;
                callButton.Enabled = true;
            }
        };

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        /*Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        button.Click += delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };*/
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: do you have a reference to Mono.Android in your project references?  Do you have a namespace conflict - as suggested below, if you name your project "Something.Android" that can cause a conflict with the base Android namespace.

Comment: I have updated my question with code... please have a look at it, thank you

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue by adding a reference to

```
Mono.Android.dll
```

Located under :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\
```

Comment: Hi @Badr, I have same problem with mac

Comment: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v12.0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your project namespace contains the Android like in `MyProject.Android`. This is mostly the cause for what you describe.

Change your namespace and it should work.

Comment: My project namespace is Phoneword, f i change that namespace to Android, Another set of errors are popping....

Comment: Can you some where post your code so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I have updated my question with code... please have a look at it, thank you

Comment: Can you publish the whole project somewhere on GitHub or Bitbucket? Looking at that single file I can't see something wrong there.